# set an image for table Header View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm trying to set `tableView.tableHeaderView` as an image

```
 var ImageHeader: UIImageView!
    let url = "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/f3/d6/71/f3d671c71d6f19d34f856103758ff203.jpg"


    ImageHeader.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: url)) // error here
    tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 40.0
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    let header = UIView(frame : CGRect(x : 0,y:0, width : tableView.frame.width , height : 100))
    header.addSubview(ImageHeader)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = header
```

This code gives me

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: In which line are you getting this error ?

Comment: check my question again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually create a `UIImageView`. So `ImageHeader` is `nil` and you force-unwrap it. Boom!

Try something like this:

```
let url = "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/f3/d6/71/f3d671c71d6f19d34f856103758ff203.jpg"

var imageHeader = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
imageHeader.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: url))
let header = UIView(frame : CGRect(x : 0,y:0, width : tableView.frame.width , height : 100))
header.addSubview(imageHeader)
tableView.tableHeaderView = header
```

Comment: `ImageView size is zero. Set its frame, call sizeToFit or force layout first. You can also set a custom format with a defined size if you don't want to force layout.`

Comment: So add a call to `sizeToFit()` as shown in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

ImageHeader is nil. You never instantiated it. Also only class names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: how can i fix this ?